# Get array/object values to another array

Tags: php, arrays, object

How to extract a single column values in an array and save them in a new array ??
Example:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 1
                [vid] => 2
                [format] => filtered_html
                [weight] => 0

            )   )

[1] => Array
    (
        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 5
                [vid] => 2
                [format] => filtered_html
                [weight] => 0
            ) )

 )
```

I want to extract the tid values and save them to a new array for example in my case i want an output to be like

```
$tid_all=array(1,5);
```

Comment: Do you get the values out of the database? You want to put those into a new array?

Comment: It may not be the cleanest way, but loop through the array twice and put the numbers into a new array?  foreach($array as array2){ foreach($array2 as $array3){ $newarray[] = $array3->tid; } }

Comment: @Marciano Nope, No I extracted them through drupal module, I have to put them into an array because I will inject it's values somwhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the array index and the `tid` are the same.  This should ease the building of the new array:

```
$tid_all = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    $tid_all = array_merge($tid_all, array_keys($values));
}
```

If there will only ever be one object in each array element then:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $tid_all[] = key($value);
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d6c3342da373a2a14179ba84a7735d6797d9310)

Comment: Yes the index is the same as the tid

Comment: Ok, and what if i wanted to extract the vid value, have you any idea about this?

Comment: Sure it is - added a DEMO link.

Comment: And for getting the vid, have you an idea about getting this ?